# \w gives me an error while using regular exprasions

Tags: c#, regex

I was using Regex and I tried to write:

```
Regex RegObj2 = new Regex("\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\w");
```

Gives me this error twice, one for each appearance of `\w`:

```
unrecognized escape sequence
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regex Issue "unrecognized escape sequence"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155219/c-sharp-regex-issue-unrecognized-escape-sequence)

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex - unrecognized escape sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318665/regex-unrecognized-escape-sequence)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a RegEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418008/how-do-i-escape-a-regex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple regex pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623787/simple-regex-pattern)

Comment: Apart from the error in how you specify the string, I think you may have some problem with the regex.

Answer (score 4):

You are not escaping the `\`s in a non-verbatim string literal.

Solution: put a `@` in front of the string or double the backslashes, as per the C# rules for [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: ... or escape the escape character, like this: `"\\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\\w"`

Answer (score 3):

Try to escape the escape ;)

```
Regex RegObj2 = new Regex("\\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\\w");
```

or add a @ (as @Dominic Kexel suggested)

Comment: or add a `@` :) (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

There are two levels of potential escaping required when writing a regular expression:

- The regular expression escaping (e.g. escaping brackets, or in this case specifying a character class)
- The C# string literal escaping

In this case, it's the latter which is tripping you up. *Either* escape the `\` so that it becomes part of the string, *or* use a verbatim string literal (with an `@` prefix) so that `\` doesn't have its normal escaping meaning. So either of these:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\w");
Regex regex2 = new Regex("\\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\\w");
```

The two approaches are absolutely equivalent at execution time. In both cases you're trying to create a string constant with the value

```
\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\w
```

The two forms are just different ways of expressing this in C# source code.

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are not being escaped e.g. `\\` or

```
new Regex(@"\w[a][b][(c|d)][(c|d)].\w");
```

Comment: Either escape the backslash or switch to a verbatim string, not both.  `@"\\w"` tries to match the literal sequence `\w`.